# program which keeps list of processes which have accessed files?

Tags: process

I was wondering if there exists a program which keeps a list of all processes which access files within a given folder. I have tried googling this, but I need to be more specific with the search terms, perhaps a keyword would be useful. I am unaware of anything which does this and would like to know if one exists, or if there might be a word associated with the kind of program which would do it.

Thanks.